# Question Concerning Polynomials in Three Variables and the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean Inequality

Tags: polynomials

There is a question that I'm having trouble with in a book on polynomials. The question is within a section on polynomials of several variables. The question has three parts. In part (a.) they ask the reader to show that :
\begin{equation}
x^{3} + y^{3} + z^{3} - 3xyz = (x+y+z) (x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} - xy - xz - yz)
\end{equation}
I was able to do this part of the question. In part (b.) they ask the reader to write :
\begin{equation}
x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} - xy - xz - yz
\end{equation}
As a sum of three squares of polynomials and deduce that this quanity is non-negative whenever x,y,z are real. I have not been able to do this.

In part (c.) they ask the reader to prove the Arithmetic-Geometric mean inequality. Here
if $a,b,c \geq 0$, then :
\begin{equation}
(abc)^{\frac{1}{3}} \leq \frac{(a+b+c)}{3}
\end{equation}
with equality if and only if $a = b = c$.

Does anyone here know of a way to do part (b.)? I suspect that part (c.) is related to the answer obtained in part (b.).

Answer (score 1):

For b,
$$x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} - xy - xz - yz=\frac12((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2).$$
For part c, you have $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz\ge0$ when $x,y,z\ge0$ from parts a and b, then let $a=x^3, b=y^3, c=z^3$.